# Angular UI Grid date filter - Filter between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I use Angular UI grid and I have a date column in which I need to have a filter that filters between start and end date. I have succeeded in implementing the date picker for the input boxes, but I am unable to filter the grid with the inputs

UI grid column definition for the specific column

```
 columnDefs: [
      {
          field: 'DocumentDate', displayName: 'Document Date', enableFiltering: true, cellFilter: 'date',
          filter: {
              condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN
          },
          filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container">
          From : <input  class="ui-grid-filter-input" date-picker type="text" ng-model="col.filters[0].term"/> 
          To : <input class="ui-grid-filter-input" date-picker type="text" ng-model="col.filters[1].term"/></div>'
      },
```

Anything that I am missing something ?

Comment: Did you ever find any solution for this? We are attempting to do the same thing.

Comment: @ShaunBowe There was no built in solution in UI Grid. Had to do a custom solution which involved a custom directive for start and end dates and then filter the grid based on the values from them using the UI grid s filter changed event,